# Map List<> to Map<Integer, Set> with additional transformation

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to convert a list of objects to a map of sets of one of the objects' property and I'd like to use Java streams for that.

For example there is a `List<Dog>` and I'd like to convert it to a `HashMap` where key is dog age and value is `Set` of breeds.

```
@Getter //lombok for getters
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int breed;
}
```

I can create `Map<Integer, Set<Dog>> dogsByAge` a by using this statement.

```
Map<Integer, Set<Dog>> dogsByAge = dogs.stream()
                                       .collect(groupingBy(Dog::getAge, toSet()));
```

However I need `Map<Integer, Set<String>> breedsByAge`

Is that possible using streams?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but it doesn't look like you have sufficient attributes to establish uniqueness... you could easily have two `Dog`s with the same age, name and breed.  Show the complete `Dog` class include the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods (you do have those, right?).

Comment: `groupingBy(Dog::getAge, Collectors.mapping(Dog::getBreed, toSet))`

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't need the uniqueness and the point of the set is to avoid duplicated breeds in the resulting. `@Data` is not well chosen, there should be `@Getter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should meet the requirement:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> breedsByAge = dogs.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dog::getAge, Collectors.mapping(Dog::getBreed, Collectors.toSet())));
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dog> dogs = List.of(new Dog("A", 10, 1), new Dog("B", 5, 1), new Dog("C", 10, 2), new Dog("D", 10, 3),
                new Dog("E", 5, 4));

        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> breedsByAge = dogs.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dog::getAge, Collectors.mapping(Dog::getBreed, Collectors.toSet())));

        System.out.println(breedsByAge);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{5=[1, 4], 10=[1, 2, 3]}
```